# PySpark least or greatest with dynamic columns

Tags: python, pyspark

I need to give a dynamic parameter to greatest in pyspark but it seems it doesn't accept that,

```
column_names=['c_'+str(x) for x in range(800)]
train_df=spark.read.parquet(train_path).select(column_names).withColumn('max_values',least(col_names))
```

So what is the way to do this without using RDDs and just dataframes

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague.

However, I have assumed you have `n` number of columns in the `train_df` and you want the `maximum` value in each row?

If thats not the case, give a sample input and ouput df.

```
  train_df=spark.createDataFrame([ (1,      1,        5,       2,      3),
(1,      1,        0,       2,      3),
(2,      3,        1,       7,      7),
(3,      6,        1,       3,      3),
(3,      6,        5,       3,      3)] ,
  ('col0' ,   'col1'   , 'col2'   , 'col3' ,   'col4' ))
  


column_names=['col'+str(x) for x in range(4)]

train_df.withColumn('max_values',array_max(array(*[x for x in column_names]))).show()


|col0|col1|col2|col3|col4|max_values|
+----+----+----+----+----+----------+
|   1|   1|   5|   2|   3|         5|
|   1|   1|   0|   2|   3|         2|
|   2|   3|   1|   7|   7|         7|
|   3|   6|   1|   3|   3|         6|
|   3|   6|   5|   3|   3|         6|
+----+----+----+----+----+----------+
```